# Limit number of matches of find command

Tags: find

If I want find command to stop after finding a certain number of matches, how do I do that?

Background is that I have too many files in a folder, I need to put them into separate folders randomly like:

```
find -max-matches 1000 -exec mv {} /path/to/collection1 \+; 
find -max-matches 1000 -exec mv {} /path/to/collection2 \+;
```

is this possible to do with `find` alone? If not, what would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I have an issue with the "randomly". Of course you *can* choose a random destination, but that means that when looking for a file that you know the name of you would have to test several (maybe all) of the subdirectories before finding the file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you're not using `find` for very much other than walking the directory tree, I'd suggest instead using the shell directly to do this.  See variations for both `zsh` and `bash` below.

---

Using the `zsh` shell

```
mv ./**/*(-.D[1,1000]) /path/to/collection1    # move first 1000 files
mv ./**/*(-.D[1,1000]) /path/to/collection2    # move next 1000 files
```

The globbing pattern `./**/*(-.D[1,1000])` would match all regular files (or symbolic links to such files) in or under the current directory, and then return the 1000 first of these.  The `-.` restricts the match to regular files or symbolic links to these, while `D` acts like `dotglob` in `bash` (matches hidden names).

This is assuming that the generated command would not grow too big through expanding the globbing pattern when calling `mv`.

The above is quite inefficient as it would expand the glob for each collection.  You may therefore want to store the pathnames in an array and then move slices of that:

```sh
pathnames=( ./**/*(-.D) )

mv $pathnames[1,1000]    /path/to/collection1
mv $pathnames[1001,2000] /path/to/collection2
```

To randomise the `pathnames` array when you create it (you mentioned wanting to move random files):

```sh
pathnames=( ./**/*(-.Doe['REPLY=$RANDOM']) )
```

---

You could do a similar thing in `bash` (except you can't easily shuffle the result of a glob match in `bash`, apart for possibly feeding the results through `shuf`, so I'll skip that bit):

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

pathnames=()
for pathname in ./**/*; do
    [[ -f $pathname ]] && pathnames+=( "$pathname" )
done

mv "${pathnames[@]:0:1000}"    /path/to/collection1
mv "${pathnames[@]:1000:1000}" /path/to/collection2
mv "${pathnames[@]:2000:1000}" /path/to/collection3
```

Comment: yes, being able to do it without find is even better.

Answer (score 20):

You can implement new tests for `find` using `-exec`:

```
seq 1 1000 |
find . -exec read \; -exec mv {} /path/to/collection1 +
```

will move the first 1000 files found to `/path/to/collection1`.

This works as follows:

- `seq 1 1000` outputs 1000 lines, piped into `find`;
- `-exec read` reads a line, failing if the pipe is closed (when `seq`’s output has been consumed);
- if the previous `-exec` succeeds, `-exec mv ...` performs the move.

`-exec ... +` works as you’d expect: `read` will run once per iteration, but `find` will accumulate matched files and call `mv` as few times as possible.

This relies on the fact that [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)’s `-exec` succeeds or fails based on the executed command’s exit status: when `read` succeeds, `find` continues processing the actions given above (because the default operator is “and”), and when it fails, `find` stops.

If your `find` supports the `-quit` action, you can use that to improve the efficiency:

```
seq 1 1000 |
find . \( -exec read \; -o -quit \) -exec mv {} /path/to/collection1 +
```

Without that, `find` will test every single file, even though it will only keep 1000 for `mv`.

I’m assuming that `read` is available as an external command, and implements [the POSIX specification for `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html); if that’s not the case, `sh -c read` can be used instead. In both cases, `find` will start a separate process for each file it checks.

Comment: to do `find -exec read` I need to have read as an external command right? the bash built-in wouldn't work?

Comment: In Archlinux, I could only find a `read` external command in the packages plan9port and 9base. It works for your application, but it doesn't seem like a typical thing to have installed. I don't know on what systems it would be usual to find it. I also don't understand what you mean with "which uses the shell's built-in". I guess it could, but at least the one from plan9port doesn't, and I don't see why it would instead of re-implementing what it could in C. The benefits of it being a shell-builtin like assigning variables can't be obtained from an external anyways.

Comment: @JoL in Fedora, the `bash` package ships a `/usr/bin/read` script which runs `builtin read "$@"`. I’ve updated my answer to address this particular issue, hopefully without the approximations of my comments! And yes, it’s one of the commands which doesn’t make much sense outside a shell context (like `cd`).

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it can be done with just `find`. You can use something like:

```
find [... your parameters ...] -print0 | head -z -1000 | xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/collection
```

`-print0`, `-z`, and `-0` work together to make sure everything works even with linefeeds in filenames.

Comment: Thank you! I was well aware of `-print0` and `xargs -0`, but not of the "-z" option (which is apparently *everywhere* and I somehow missed it all these years... Just saw that it's there in `cut`, `sed`, `tail` and probably all coreutils... As for the `-t` option of `mv`, I guess it was tailor-made for `xargs` - with the more general (not `mv`-specific) solution for this something along the lines of `xargs -i somecommand {} targetFolder/`.

Comment: @ttsiodras `-z` is a recent discovery for myself too...

Answer (score 4):

I think, it is not possible directly with find, but you can use a pipe with head and xargs like:

> find ... | head -1000 | xargs -i mv "{} /path/to/collection1"

This moves the first 1000 files to collection1.

Answer (score 2):

Stephens answer 264963 is probably best for my use-case but there is a simple workaround for the use-case in this question with only find and head:

```
find . [checks] -print -exec ... | head
```

The `-print` will be evaluated before the `-exec` (At least on CentOS 8) and the pipe to head will cause `find` to quit when `head` closes the pipe.